# Changes made on application.bootstrap.scss doesn't reflect on the browser Rails 7

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-5

I have this really weird problem where the changes I made to `application.bootstrap.scss` doesn't reflect on the browser.

Here's the content of the `application.bootstrap.scss`

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';

.mt-n4 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -4rem;
}

.avatar-sm {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar-section" "content-section";
  grid-template-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar-layout {
  grid-area: navbar-section;
}

.content-layout {
  grid-area: content-section;
}
```

when I change the `background-color` of `.main-layout` to `blue` the change is reflected on the compiled file under `app/assets/build/application.css` but checking the css source on the browser, it's still `yellow`, even after refreshing and clearing the cache.

I am currently running the server using `./bin/dev` and when I run `rails r "print Rails.env"`, I get `development%`.

My temporary workaround is to close the server and run these commands:

```
rm -rf app/assets/build/*
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake assets:precompile
./bin/dev # Running ./bin/dev immediately after clearing cache doesn't work.
```

and the changes are reflected on the browser...but only after I execute these commands. Now I have to execute them whenever I make changes to the stylesheet.

Are there any other (easier) workaround for this? If not, then is there a way I can automatically execute the commands whenever I run `./bin/dev`?